# Ejecutar comandos Unix(linux) desde Python

Tags: python-3.x, json, debian, mqtt, sh

He estado intentar ejecutar un comando de envió a través de Python, el cual ejecuta un documento sh que manda un JSON a ThingsBoard, el problema es que no logro 'encontrar' la manera de poder ejecutar el comando desde Python para que se envíe el JSON.
El comando que uso para enviar manualmente el JSON es `sh enviar.sh`, esta es la forma en la que intento ejecutar el comando en python:

```
envioDatos1.py


import os
import subprocess
#import shlex
import json
from subprocess import call

#enviar = subprocess.check_output('sh enviar.sh')

subprocess.call(['sh', 'enviar.sh'])

#subprocess.call('enviar.sh')
#call('date')
#os.system('enviar.sh')

# command_line = 'sh enviar.sh'
# args = shlex.split(command_line)
# subprocess.call(args)
```

El código comentado son todas las formas en que he intentado resolver el problema y no funciona, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
PS C:\Users\abner\OneDrive - Nordata\ThingsBoard\MQTT> & "C:/Program Files/Python38/python.exe" "c:/Users/abner/OneDrive - Nordata/ThingsBoard/MQTT/envioDatos1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/abner/OneDrive - Nordata/ThingsBoard/MQTT/envioDatos1.py", line 12, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['sh', 'enviar.sh'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```

El archivo que quiero ejecutar es:

```
enviar.sh


#!/bin/sh
    # Set ThingsBoard host to "demo.thingsboard.io" or "localhost"
    THINGSBOARD_HOST="10.10.0.118"
    # Replace YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN with one from Device details panel.
    ACCESS_TOKEN="Pureba6ITG"
    # Publish serial number and firmware version attributes
    mosquitto_pub -d -h "$THINGSBOARD_HOST" -t "v1/devices/me/attributes" -u "$ACCESS_TOKEN" -f "attributes-data.json"
    # Publish timeseries data as an object without timestamp (server-side timestamp will be used)
    mosquitto_pub -d -h "$THINGSBOARD_HOST" -t "v1/devices/me/telemetry" -u "$ACCESS_TOKEN" -f "data.json"
```

Este código a su vez envía este json al Host de ThingsBoard definido:

```
[{"Mac": "F8033201CC50", "Timestamp": 1597848689081577, "Modelo": "model", "Version": "itg200"}, {"Nombre dispositivo": "Temperatura_itg200_2", "Unidad de medida": "Cel", "Valor": 25.687}, {"Tipo de dispositivo": "gateway", "Mac asociada": "F8033201CC50"}]
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Hola Abner, una pregunta: ¿intentar ejecutar un script de shell (linux) en un powershell (Windows)? El error entiendo que es Python no encontrando `sh`

Comment: Así es, acabo de instalar el sh en python y el error cambio.

Comment: Creo que desde windows no se pueden ejecutar scripts linux, asi hallas instalado cygwin o cosas parecidas, puede que la compatibilidad total no se logre, por lo cual te pregunto... Estas seguro de que todos los comandos que usas en tu script sh son reconocidos por el sh que instalaste en tu windows? porque de lo contrario el problema puede estar en tu script sh

Answer (score -1):

tu error es que estas intentando ejecutar un subproceso que no está disponible en Windows por defecto. `sh` es un comando de Linux y aunque se puede conseguir de distintas maneras para Windows, es muy probable que tu script de shell esté esperando un entorno Linux y pueda fallar (como por ejemplo la linea `#!/bin/sh`)

Lo que no entiendo es por qué has añadido la etiqueta `debian` si no estas usando Linux.